# Corsair RAM not working in Dell Demension 8300

Tags: memory, dell-dimension

Okay, so I built myself a computer and gave my old Dell Demension 8300 to my brother.  I kept the hard drives, and, when he went to buy a new one, he got some extra RAM (DDR).  Not being very technical himself, he called me over to help.  We took an old pair of 256 meg sticks out and put in a new pair of Corsair 512's in.  When we powered it on, it just beeped for a while and refused to send any output to the monitor.  After some trial and error, we figured out that the board just doesn't like the Corsair RAM at all.  I examined the sticks and found that the Corsair was CL2, while the set we had taken out was CL3.  Other than that, it didn't' look like there was a major difference.  Is this CL- difference the source of the problem?

Comment: Please find an user manual or spec sheet for that laptop and see if it can take 512 in one stick. Lower CL is better, so it shouldn't affect your laptop since it should set CL3 if it can't do CL2 for some reason. There's one way that CL2 could be the problem - that is if Corsair didn't program their memory with CL3 timings at all, which I doubt. In this case setting memory timings in bios manually (disable auto-detection) while 256's are in, and then plugging 512's back could be effective.

Comment: It's a desktop, not a laptop.

Comment: This is still true for desktops.

Comment: It said it can handle a gig per stick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either your RAM isn't seated correctly or it's the wrong kind for your system.

If it happens to be the first issue simply remove the new RAM and reset it to ensure it has clicked into place. Another one you can try here is use one at a time to ensure one isn't faulty.

If you continue to get the beep tone you likely need new RAM. I suggest Crucial for your RAM. See  [here](http://www.crucial.com/uk/store/listparts.aspx?model=Dimension%208300%20Series&Cat=RAM) for a list of RAM for your system.

Comment: I've already confirmed that they're both bad, but I'll see if I can find Crucial for a good price.